# Umbraco V8 installation with more than 25 000 members and public profile pages for each member

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, umbraco8

I am currently scoping a project that needs to be reworked so Umbraco V8 is part of it. This projects already has 18 000 members and 5 000 more are for sure on their way.

- Does anybody here had experience with Umbraco with so many members?
  And if so what should I expect and beware of?
- Another thing is: I will need to generate public profile pages for
  each member. (https://justnik.me/blog/creating-a-public-profile-page-for-members-in-umbraco-part-1 <- Any idea  of how efficient is this approach ? )

***My primary concerns are:***

- Is Umbraco capable of handling this amount of members without taking a
  hit on the performance when loading information from the members
  property?
- Should I add my own tables to help the performance?
- Having 25,000+ member nodes how much will it slow the manegment of
  the members via the Umbraco interface. However what if I just use my
  own manegment tool for this level of members?

Comment: Maybe you should even consider Umbraco 9 for this? .NET Core is generally very well performing, although I don't know of any specific numbers for members. You could try asking over on https://our.umbraco.com/forum/ as well .

Comment: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/106845-umbraco-v8-installation-with-more-than-25-000-members-and-public-profile-pages-for-each-member#comment-332733 @JannikAnker

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work, since it uses the ASP.NET membership provider, which runs on an SQL server, so you're only limited to SQL Server specs, so later if you facing any issues then scale up the specs.

If you have a large number of members, then try to fetch from [MembersIndex](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Searching/Examine/examine-manager) instead of using the [MemberService](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IMemberService.html).